# Payment Processor for UK

Tags: payment-processor, payment

Which UK payment processors are most recommended to use with CiviCRM? (aside from PayPal)?

Answer (score 1):

[Sage Pay](https://www.sagepay.co.uk) is a tried and tested UK payment processor that works well with CiviCRM -

https://github.com/circleinteractive/uk.co.circleinteractive.payment.sagepay

Answer (score 1):

[Stripe](https://stripe.com/gb) is also tried & tested in the UK and personally I'd recommend it - the extension is [here](https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe). I particularly like Stripe's website which has been designed around taking online payments.